# Query Coordinates in Firebase with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-places-api

I have a Firebase database with data like so:

```
{
    "city name" : {
        "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 1,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "Best Buy",
           "ratingCount" : 1
        },
        "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 3,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "Indigo",
           "ratingCount" : 1
        },
        "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 3,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "Catholic Parish",
           "ratingCount" : 1
        },
        "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 2,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "Mac's",
           "ratingCount" : 1
        },
        "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 2,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "School",
           "ratingCount" : 1
       },
       "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 4,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "Church",
           "ratingCount" : 1
       },
       "uniqueId" : {
           "averageRating" : 4,
           "createdBy" : "someDood",
           "latitude" : 1234,
           "longitude" : 4321,
           "name" : "Mall",
           "ratingCount" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to query specific coordinates within two sets of coordinates.

lower latitude,
upper latitude,
lower longitude,
upper longitude

Is this possible to do in Firebase? I'm trying to query all points I've added that are currently in the user's `MKMapView`. I have the Google Places API as well but It seems the only way to get nearby locations like this through that is by using the picker which I don't want to do.

Comment: Try looking at geofire third party library

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks @Dravidian that's exactly what I was looking for.